# How do I become root on a remote server until I am disconnected from that server?

Tags: linux

So far I have this:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -q username@192.168.167.654 " [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ] && exec sudo -- "$0" "$@" ; whoami ; [run some commands as root]"
```

I keeps giving me username as answer from whoami. I want to be root as soon as I am connected to the server (but I can only connect to it with username). How can I be root throughout the connection to the server?

Clarification:

I want to access a remote server. It is mandatory that I connect as "username" and then switch to root to run and copy files that only root is able to do. So while I am connected to that server via ssh, I want to be root until my commands are over in the remote server. My problem is that I am not able to do so because I don't have the knowledge, hence I am posting it here.

Restrictions:

- can't use rsync.
- have to connect to the server as "username" and then switch to root
- this code is in a for loop so I don't want to use `su` because it will keep asking for a password

Comment: I'm not sure `exec sudo --...` is doing what you think it is

Answer (score 2):

I don't think sudo is going to work they way you are hoping it will work.

If you have a command like `sudo ... ; blah` the initial shell is what interprets the `;`.  So the sudo command is issued, and after that closes, then the blah command is executed by the shell.

I would probably be tempted to change your command so you do something like this.  The examples below assumes that sudo will not prompt you for a password, because you have setup NOPASSWD.

```
echo "commands to run on remote" | sshpass -p "password" ssh -q username@192.168.167.654 "exec sudo /bin/bash"
```

A simple example would be to do something like `echo whoami | sudo bash`.

You also do something like this.

```
cat <<REMOTECOMMANDS | sshpass -p "password" ssh -q username@192.168.167.654 "exec sudo /bin/bash"
whoami
command1
command2
command2
REMOTECOMMANDS
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use `su`](http://www.linfo.org/su.html).

> The su (short for substitute user) command makes it possible to change a login session's owner (i.e., the user who originally created that session by logging on to the system) without the owner having to first log out of that session.
> [...]
>  A simplified expression of the syntax of the su command is:
> su [options] [commands] [-] [username]

Although, really, you should just [`sudo`](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306766:linux-101-introduction-to-sudo) all your commands, but... `su` is how you do what you asked.

Comment: Already have, check the last restriction I wrote

Comment: I am not sure why you think su would make a difference over sudo?  Replacing one for the other in his command wouldn't changing anything, other then requiring the root password.

Comment: @Zoredache I figured he was going to SSH in as a normal user, `su` to switch the logged in session to `root`, and then run his commands, rather than use `su` or `sudo` within his command.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo -i` for an interactive root shell.

Use `sudo command` or `sudo -i command` to run a command as root. The `-i` option sets up a shell and environment before running the command.

Comment: Is that really going to help though?  He wants to run the commands following the sudo invocation as root.  If you look at his example `sudo -i; whoami`  The whoami command wouldn't get run with root privileges.

Comment: Not really. He's got to write a script.